# What does this regular expression try to match?

Tags: regex, tcl

These days I am learning [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), but it seems like a little hard to me. I am reading some code in TCL, but what does it want to match?

```
regexp ".* (\[\\d]\{3\}:\[\\d]\{3\}:\[\\d]\{3\}.\[\\d]\{5\}).\[^\\n]" $input
```

Comment: what language are you writing this regex in?

Comment: seems like all the programming language use the same rules for regex?

Comment: @ratzip not true; Have a look at the differences between POSIX BRE / ERE and PCRE, among other flavours. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: This regex demands 2 characters after the capturing group. You may need this instead: `.(?:$|\[^\\n])` to hit the end-of-string *or* a non-newline character.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you un-escape the characters, you get the following:

```
.* ([\d]{3}:[\d]{3}:[\d]{3}.[\d]{5}).[^\n]
```

The term `[\d]{x}` would match `x` number of consecutive digits.  Therefore, the portion inside the parentheses would match something of the form `###:###:###?#####` (where `#` can be any digit and `?` can be any character).  The parentheses themselves aren't matched, they're just used for specifying what part of the input to "capture" and return to the caller.  Following this sequence is a single dot `.`, which matches a single character (which can be anything).  The trailing `[^\n]` will match a single character that is anything *except* a newline (a `^` at the start of a bracketed expression inverts the match).  The `.*` term at the very beginning matches a sequence of characters of any length (even zero), followed by a space.

With all of this taken into account, it appears that this regular expression extracts a series of digits from the middle of a line.  Given the format of the numbers, it may be looking for a timestamp in the `hours:minutes:seconds.milliseconds` format (although if that is the case, `{1,3}` and `{1,5}` should be used instead).  The trailing `.[^\n]` term looks like it could be trying to exclude timestamps that are at or near the end of a line.  Timestamped logs often have a timestamp followed by some sort of delimiting character (`:`, `>`, a space, etc).  A regular expression like this might be used to extract timestamps from the log while ignoring "blank" lines that have a timestamp but no message.

**Update:**
Here's an example using TCL 8.4:

```
% set re ".* (\[\\d]\{3\}:\[\\d]\{3\}:\[\\d]\{3\}.\[\\d]\{5\}).\[^\\n]"
% regexp $re "TEST: 123:456:789:12345> sample log line"
1
% regexp $re " 111:222:333.44444 foo"
1
% regexp $re "111:222:333.44444 foo"
0
% regexp $re " 111:222:333.44444 "
0
% regexp $re " 10:44:56.12344: "
0
%
% regexp $re "TEST: 123:456:789:12345> sample log line" match data
1
% puts $match
TEST: 123:456:789:12345>
% puts $data
123:456:789:12345
```

The first two examples match the expression.  The third fails because it lacks the space character before the first number sequence.  The fourth fails because it doesn't have a non-newline character at the end after the trailing space.  The fifth fails because the numerical sequences don't have enough digits.  By passing parameters after the input, you can store the part of the input that matched the expression as well as the data that was "captured" by using parentheses.  See [the TCL wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/986) for details on the `regexp` command.

The interesting part with TCL is that you have to escape the `[` character but not the `]`, while both the `{` and `}` need escaping.

Comment: You'd matching something along this format - "333:333:333-54322eg" with the e=(".") matching any chars except line break. Same goes for ("[^\n]").

Comment: The regexp definition would have been a lot easier to read if the original programmer had just used {} instead of "". The {} inside it are balanced so they wouldn't cause a problem, and it would mean a lot less escaping.

Comment: With Tcl's REs, `[\d]` and `\d` are exactly equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

```
.* ==> match junk part of the input

 ( ==> start capture

 \[\\d]\{3\}: ==> match 3 digits followed by ':'

 \[\\d]\{3\}: ==> match 3 digits followed by ':'

 \[\\d]\{3\}. ==> match 3 digits followed by any character

\[\\d]\{5\} ==> match 5 digits

). ==> close capture and match any character

\[^\\n] ==> match a character that is not a newline
```

Comment: The "\\d" is actually escaping the char d so this doesn't capture digits anymore but is literally looking for the letter "d" in this case.

Comment: @DennisRongo- Not true.  When the command is processed, one layer of escapes is stripped off.  The `\[\\d]` sequence is seen as `[\d]` when the regex engine gets it, so this will match a digit and not the letter 'd'.  See my answer for examples (you can add a `puts $re` to see the expression after the escapes have been processed).